# Why are there two 我们 in 我们在等船来渡我们过河?

Tags: translation, grammar, meaning

> 我们在等船来渡我们过河。

Supposedly this translates to “We are waiting for the boat to cross the river.” But what does the second 我们 mean? Is there maybe more nuance than this English translation shows?

Comment: This could be context related. If A & B were leaving, C & D were saying goodbye to A & B at the dock, then if the conversation happened between E & A,B: E: "What you guys doing last night?" A,B: "We are waiting for the boat to carry **us** to cross the river". If the conversation happened between E & C,D: "What you guys doing last night?" C,D: "We are waiting for the boat to carry **them** to cross the river".

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just say: "我们在等船渡河。"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe this translation would be more understandable:

> We are waiting for the boat to **take us to** cross the river.

Answer (score 2):

When you translate the sentence into "We are waiting for the boat to cross the river."You don't get the word 渡，maybe the meaning is the same, you can translate the 渡 into "carry somebody to someplace" so you should add 我们 for "carry us  to the other side of the river".In a word,in that sentence, we can get two actions, one is "wait for the boat",the other is "carry us away".So you should use two 我们.